# Global Style in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have set some styles in the App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="HotPink"/>
</Style>
```

This style works on normal controls, but not inside DataTemplates

```
<TextBlock Text="Test"></TextBlock> <!-- Works here -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.UniverseGroups}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RelativePanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <!-- This text still is black -->
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Is there a way to make global styles work even inside DataTemplates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, as in your case, it will be overridden by the `Foreground` of the `ItemsControl`. So you will have to add the following to your `App.xaml`.

```
<Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="HotPink"/>
</Style>
```

When you are dealing with more advanced `ItemsControl` like `ListView` that supports `ItemContainerStyle`, you will need to set the `TargetType` to its item container (i.e. `ListViewItem`) instead.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value ="HotPink"/>
</Style>
```